# Login in my Flutter app is disabled as Facebook app is disabled due to violation of Platform term 4.b policy?

Tags: flutter, facebook, privacy-policy

Facebook has disabled my app due to following reasons:

Platform Terms 4.b: Your privacy policy must comply with applicable law and regulations and must accurately and clearly explain what data you are Processing, how you are Processing it, the purposes for which you are Processing it, and how Users may request deletion of that data.

During testing, we found that your privacy policy doesn’t explain what data you are processing. Update your privacy policy to include this information before you submit an appeal.

Platform Terms 4.b: Your privacy policy must comply with applicable law and regulations and must accurately and clearly explain what data you are Processing, how you are Processing it, the purposes for which you are Processing it, and how Users may request deletion of that data.

During testing, we found that your privacy policy doesn’t explain the purposes for which you are processing data. Update your privacy policy to include this information before you submit an appeal.

Platform Terms 4.b: Your privacy policy must comply with applicable law and regulations and must accurately and clearly explain what data you are Processing, how you are Processing it, the purposes for which you are Processing it, and how Users may request deletion of that data.

During testing, we found that your privacy policy doesn’t explain how users can request data deletion. Update your privacy policy to include this information before you submit an appeal.

Privacy policy link of my app:
https://vjdjapps.in/policies/seep/privacypolicy.html

I have updated this link in Facebook app -> settings -> basic -> privacy policy field.
I have updated this in appstore and google play store listing too.
I am not sure now what else I can do. They simply reject citing the above reasons. Its been almost over a month that my app is disabled and login is not working in my app. Please help.

Comment: I was having the same issues and got mine through [iUbenda](http://iubenda.refr.cc/K5W7JXD) It is pretty straight forward and gives you everything explicitly and with the easy. to read boxes

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether you have changed *everywhere*. e.g. does Facebook console have a text field pointing to outdated version of privacy policy?
2. Check whether the webpage has improper cache such that they see an old version.
3. Does Facebook have human-being customer service? If so contact them and ask for details.

I know it is very, very annoying to deal with such kinds of things, since I have also experienced similar things from other services :(

Comment: I have tried to contact them but they are not replying. Its almost 2 months since my app is banned.

Comment: @vijay053 Have you tried my three points and does it work? If so you can award the bounty